# Display correct subtraction of two timestamps in create view

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, timezone, timestamp

By using normal minus '-' function between two timestamps, the answer given from oracle is incorrect.

This is what i want to do:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH24:MI TZR';
```

Created table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
   StartTime timestamp with time zone
  ,EndTime   timestamp with time zone
  ,Science   varchar2(7)
);
```

I create the column data type as timestamp with time zone. This is value I have inserted:

```
INSERT INTO TEST 
VALUES('05-OCT-2013 01:00 +08:00'
      ,'05-OCT-2013 23:00 +06:00'
      ,'SCIENCE');

INSERT INTO TEST 
VALUES('05-OCT-2013 12:00 +08:00'
      ,'05-OCT-2013 15:00 -12:00'
      ,'Maths');
```

Attempted for rounding time:

```
CREATE VIEW TESTRECRDS AS
SELECT (Extract(hour FROM(ENDTIME- STARTTIME)) || 'Hours' || 
Extract(minute FROM(ENDTIME- STARTTIME))>=60 Then (Extract(hour FROM(ENDTIME- STARTTIME)) + Extract(minute FROM(ENDTIME- STARTTIME))/60 ELSE 0 END || 'Minutes' AS DURATION,
Science
FROM Test;
```

Now i have two questions regarding on the calculation and rounding off the minutes to nearest hours.
First let's say the endtime is 1535 +0600 and starttime is 01:50 +0800
So when i deduct endtime - starttime:
the formula should be:

```
2135 - 0950 = 2085 - 0950
= 1135
```

But if i use my successful attempt answer to calculate, it is not the correct exact answer. The oracle answer would be 15 hours 45 minutes.

Comment: There isn't a data type that does this (to my knowledge) - what's the harm in using a `DATE` data type if you only want the timezone from it?

Comment: ok i would like to insert timestamp with timezone during creation of my tables. Can DATE data type do that too?

Comment: @user976050: No. The date datatype does not include a time zone. Think about it. "Date" is independent of time zones.

Comment: Why `STARTTIME- ENDTIME`? It should be `ENDTIME - STARTTIME` to get a positive value. Why multiply it by 24? It makes helping hard, when you don't explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and updated my solution due to removing my 24 for hours and duration. Yes is endtime-starttime. So if i deduct in this way, the oracle would not give me 1135 as the correct answer. The answer in oracle would be 15 hours 45 minutes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last `CREATE VIEW` statement you try to multiply `text`, which cannot work:

```
SELECT To_Char(STARTTIME - ENDTIME, 'HH24:MI TZR')*24 AS DURATION
```

`*24` is operating on the text `to_char()` returns. 
You have to multiply the interval *before* converting to text.

---

You define the column `Science varchar2(6)`, then you insert `'SCIENCE'`, a 7-letter word?

---

I also fixed a syntax error in your INSERT statement: missing `'`.

---

About your comment:
"I would like to insert timestamp with timezone during creation of my tables. Can DATE data type do that too?

Read about [data types in the manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847).
The data type `date` does not include time zone information.

---

If by "timezone difference" you mean the difference between the timezone modifiers, use this to calculate:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(timezone_hour FROM STARTTIME) AS tz_modifier FROM tbl
```

Keywords here are `timezone_hour` and is `timezone_minute`. Read [more in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm#SQLRF00639).

But be aware that these numbers depend on the daylight saving hours and such shenanigans. Very uncertain territory!

---

Get it in pretty format - example:

```
SELECT to_char((EXTRACT (timezone_hour FROM STARTTIME) * 60
              + EXTRACT (timezone_minutes FROM STARTTIME))
              * interval '1 min', 'HH:MI')
```

In PostgreSQL you would have the simpler `EXTRACT (timezone FROM STARTTIME)`, but I don't think Oracle supports that. Can't test now.

---

Here is a  simple demo how you could round minutes to hours:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM (ENDTIME - STARTTIME))
     + CASE WHEN EXTRACT(minute FROM (ENDTIME - STARTTIME)) >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Test;
```

Comment: Ok From your statement i created this: 
SELECT To_Char((STARTTIME - ENDTIME)*24, 'HH24:MI TZR')AS DURATION
But what i really wanted is to calculate the timezone difference out and populate the number of hours only.

Comment: @user976050: Please define `timezone difference` and `populate the number of hours`. I am trying to understand, but fail. Best edit examples into your question, what the outcome should look like. That would help everybody to understand.

Comment: Hi I have updated my inserted table and created table. For my latest solution, i can calculate the different time stamps between starttime and endtime. However, it doesn't help me to calculate the timezone difference. Is oracle able to calculate the timezone difference ? And add into the Duration.

Comment: @user976050: see my amended answer for more on timezone difference.

Comment: Understood from your given sample. I have modified mine. And now i have another issue which is how to extract and combine hours and minutes together such as that results would be hours -->(hours) 11.50 <--(min)

Comment: @user976050: I added an example.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my latest attempt and there's a error during conversion of char. The only thing now i wish is to combine the extraction of day and minute together into duration column.

Comment: @user976050: replace `+` with the string concatenation operator `||` when dealing with strings. Remember that EXTRACT returns a number, while to_char() returns a test string (nvarchar). You really need to know these basics.

Comment: Hi Erwin, yes i'll buck up my basics and my careless mistakes. I forgot that i should replace the + instead of ||. Apologize for my mistake. There is one more question i would like to ask.. Let's say the start time is 13:30 +0800 and endtime is 1605 +0600. and i use my above method to subtract. The answer will not be exact minutes and time. For example answer is 0days11hours70minutes. Is there any way or formula to round to the nearest hour? Thanks

Comment: @user976050: added yet another answer to my answer. :)

Comment: Hi Erwin, I have updated my solution. There's a step missing if i'm not wrong. Because if there minutes is more than 60, it will only divide the minutes and shown as result rather than adding onto it. How can i define ||'hours'|| as a attribute or something so that my then statement results can populate in it?

Answer (score 0):

To round you will need to do a bit of more math.  Try something like:

TO_DATE(ROUND((ENDTIME - STARTTIME) * 96) / 96, 'HH24:MI')

The difference between dates is in days.  Multiplying by 96 changes the measure to quarter hours.  Round, then convert back to days, and format.  It might be better to use a numeric format want to format, in which case you would divide by 4 instead of 96.

Timezone is not particularly relevant to a time difference. You will have to adjust the difference from UTC to that timezone to get the right result with Timezone included.

Comment: Please take a look at what i have edited. Now i only want it to display HH24:MI TZR after subtracting.

Comment: New answer replies to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what number you're trying to calculate, but when you subtract two dates in Oracle, you get the difference between the dates in units of days, not a `DATE` datatype

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2011-01-01 09:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') - 
       TO_DATE('2011-01-01 08:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS diff 
  FROM dual

      DIFF
----------
.041666667
```

In this case 8am and 9am are 0.41667 days apart. This is not a date object, this is a scalar number, so formatting it as HH24:MI doesn't make any sense.

Comment: From your given solution, this is what i did in the first place where i create my table and the attribute for start time and end time is date format. But now i want it to subtract for timezone difference too. If i do in your way, it doesn't calculate timezone.

Comment: Are you saying you want to take the difference in the two timestamps, taking the timezones into account?

Comment: Yes. I have amended my solution and now i wish to combine two extractions into one column.